# Multiple OR operators in a single IF

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How to have multiple OR operators in a single if statement? I tried this way but there's an error of:

> Incompatible data types in expression or assignment.

I looked at documentation of length function and it is  `LENGTH ( {string | raw-expression | blob-field } [ , type ] )`?

Here's the code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cMonth AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE cDay AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE cYear AS CHARACTER.

UPDATE cDateFromUser.

cDay = (SUBSTRING(cDateFromUser,1,2)).
cMonth = (SUBSTRING(cDateFromUser,3,2)).
cYear = (SUBSTRING(cDateFromUser,5,4)).

IF (LENGTH(cDay <> 2)) OR (LENGTH(cMonth <> 2)) OR (LENGTH(cYear <> 4)) THEN DO:
    /*Code*/
END.
ELSE DO:
    /*Code*/
END.
```

Comment: While the answer below is correct regarding OR handling, why are you asking the user for a date in a character variable when you could just be using a date variable? If you need format dd/mm/yyyy while your session format is something else then you could set SESSION:DATE-FORMAT = "dmy" - and set the format of your variables as "99/99/9999" - do not forget to restore the date-format in a finally block.

Comment: That's a valid point, this was done as an exercise of type conversion and data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is not right here. Use the following IF:

```
IF (LENGTH(cDay) <> 2) OR (LENGTH(cMonth) <> 2) OR (LENGTH(cYear) <> 4) THEN DO:
```

Comment: While extra parentheses /can/ help readability, they are not necessary in this case and imho just add noise.